# Do all fields have a total cyclic order?

Tags: logic, ring-theory, field-theory, nonstandard-models

It is well known the finite commutative rings, $Z/nZ$, are not [discretely ordered rings](http://web.mat.bham.ac.uk/R.W.Kaye/logic/dor.html). The axiom $\forall x \forall y \forall z((0<z \land x<y) \rightarrow (x*z < y*z))$ is false for the rings $Z/nZ$. However, these rings do have a [total cyclic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_order).

It is easy to define a partial cyclic order for these rings. A common way of defining a partial cyclic order uses the betweenness operator, $B(x,y,z)$, which means $y$ comes after $x$ and before $z$. A simple way to define a partial cyclic order would be $\forall x(B(x,x+1,x+2))$. Determining whether a partial cyclic order can be extended to a total cyclic order is an NP-complete problem. 3SAT can be converted into a partial cyclic order extension problem.

Assume we start with the standard [field axioms](http://people.reed.edu/~mayer/math112.html/html1/node16.html) and add the following axioms for total cyclic order:

Define Distinct, D(x,y,z), and eliminate troublesome models

D1) $\forall x \forall y \forall z(D(x,y,z) \leftrightarrow (x \neq y \land x \neq z \land y \neq z))$

D2) $\exists x \exists y \exists z(D(x,y,z))$

Partial Cyclic Order, B(x,y,z)

PC1) $\forall x \forall y \forall z(B(x,y,z) \rightarrow B(y,z,x))$

PC2) $\forall x \forall y \forall z(B(x,y,z) \rightarrow \neg B(z,y,x))$

PC3) $\forall w \forall x \forall y \forall z((B(w,x,y) \land B(w,y,z)) \rightarrow B(w,x,z))$

Total Cyclic Order

TC1) $\forall x \forall y \forall z(D(x,y,z) \rightarrow (B(x,y,z) \lor B(z,y,x))$

Link Successor and Addition to Cyclic Order

L1) $\forall x(B(x,x+1,x+2))$

L2) $\forall w \forall x \forall y \forall z(B(x,y,z) \leftrightarrow B(x+w,y+w,z+w))$

The rings $Z/pZ$ where $p$ is prime are models of this theory. By compactness and Lowenhiem-Skolem there exists a countably infinite model of this theory. Are there are any algebraically closed fields that are models of this theory? Are there any fields that do not have a total cyclic order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your axioms do not involve multiplication at all (other than referring to $1$, and the only property of $1$ used is that it is a nonzero element), so the existence of a total cyclic order on a field depends only on its additive structure.  Since any totally order on a field induces a cyclic order satisfying your axioms and there exist totally ordered fields which have any dimension over $\mathbb{Q}$, it follows that every field of characteristic $0$ can be totally cyclically ordered.

On the other hand, no field of characteristic $2$ can be totally cyclically ordered, since in such a field axiom L1 says $B(x,x+1,x)$, which is incompatible with axiom PC2.  I don't know what you can say about fields of characteristic $p>2$.

Comment: Axiom D2 also rules out characteristic 2. I am interested in discreet orders as well. I almost included the axiom $\forall x(\neg B(0,x,1))$ but I assumed this would make the question much harder.